# Remote Go Registry to a self hosted Git repo (not Github/Gitlab/bitbucket)

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, go-modules

How can I create a remote repo to a Git server, which is not GitHub, and is hosted on prem (along with Artifactory)?

We currently use `Go mod` or `Glide` with "regular" git clone and no Artifactory. In order to make the transition from "regular" to Artifactory smooth, I have to create a remote registry to point to my Git server and setup `GOPROXY`. Since part of the artifacts will be in Artifactory Go-local and part of them will be in the Git server I might be facing a problem. I think that even JFrog-cli tool will have to make 2 step to pull the data (first with `--no-registry` and the second "with-registry").

Since the docs explains only how to setup Github and GoCenter remote registries, and I would like to be able to pull code from any other type of git servers as well.

Comment: Jfrog CLI can populate Artifactory with all the dependecies it doesn't find in Artifactory, but does find in the VCS. You don't have to set the GOPROXY env var for this, because JFrog CLI will set it with the details of the Artifactory server. All you need to do is to run "jfrog rt go-config" while in the root of the project, and then "jfrog rt go build".

Comment: Adding to my last comment, for the CLI to publish the missing dependencies to Artifactory, you'll need to specify a deployment repository when running the "jfrog rt go-config" command.

Comment: What if the only thing I would like to do is `go get` with `GOPROXY`? I would rather contain the `jfrog-cli` usage only to the CI system (for now) and continue use the "go standards" to fetch the modules. So... is it possible to create a remote registry to our "git server"?

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe is it possible to proxy (remote-repo) other Git repos and not just GitHub?